# View only updated by EnvironmentObject after App-restart

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have this weird behaviour, which I have been trying to fix for many hours:

One of my views is not being updated when the EnvironmentObject `UserSettings` changes. Although if I restart the App completely, the new value is used as it should.

Here is a short gif: https://s8.gifyu.com/images/Screen-Recording-2020-11-17-at-15.36.07.gif

So the value is stored properly and the View is accessing the right instance but since it is @Published, I would expect it to change instantly like in the other view. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

I built a small App that shows the same behaviour:

UserSettings.swift

```
import SwiftUI

final class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var colorSelection: Int {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(colorSelection, forKey: "colorSelection")
        }
    }
    
    @Published var qnh: Double {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(qnh, forKey: "qnh")
        }
    }
    
    @Published var offset: Double {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(offset, forKey: "offset")
        }
    }
    
    @Published var colors: Array<Color> {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(colors, forKey: "colors")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        self.colorSelection = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "colorSelection") as? Int ?? 0
        self.qnh = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "qnh") as? Double ?? 1013.25
        self.offset = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "offset") as? Double ?? 0
        self.colors = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "colors") as? Array ?? [Color.green, Color.white, Color.red, Color.blue, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.pink, Color.purple, Color.black]
    }
}
```

TestApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(UserSettings())
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State var view = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $view) {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(UserSettings())
                .tabItem {Image(systemName: "location")}
                .tag(0)
            NavigationView {
                SettingsView()
                    .environmentObject(UserSettings())
                    .navigationTitle("Settings")
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "gearshape")}
            .tag(2)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(UserSettings())
    }
}
```

MainView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    
    var body: some View {
       Text("Test")
        .foregroundColor(userSettings.colors[userSettings.colorSelection])
    }
}
```

SettingsView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State private var selection: Int = 0
    private let colors = ["Green", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Pink", "Purple", "Black"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Customize")) {
                Picker(selection: $userSettings.colorSelection, label: Text("Font Color")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< colors.count) {
                        Text(self.colors[$0]).foregroundColor(userSettings.colors[$0])
                    }.foregroundColor(userSettings.colors[userSettings.colorSelection])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating new objects of UserSetting and passing them to the subview. You should create that object ones and pass it to the subviews.

In your ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State var view = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $view) {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(userSetting) //<< here pass the correct one
                .tabItem {Image(systemName: "location")}
                .tag(0)
            NavigationView {
                SettingsView()
                    .environmentObject(userSetting) //<< here aswell
                    .navigationTitle("Settings")
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "gearshape")}
            .tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

And its actually even simpler as you do not have to pass that manually to the subview. Just declare

```
@EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
```

in your views and you can access it, without passing it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that was impossible since i declared it as "final"!

Comment: @davidev I didn't notice it's the same environment, your edit should actually be on top ;)

Comment: @pawello2222 Yeah.. it is working really nice in SwiftUI. Thanks, still you did the correct answer little bit earlier though. I'm too slow :P

Answer (score 2):

If you call `UserSettings()` it will create a **new instance** of your class.

You need to pass the correct `UserSettings` instance (instead of creating a new one):

MainView.swift

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(userSettings) // pass here
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
MainView()
    .environmentObject(userSettings) // pass here
    .tabItem { Image(systemName: "location") }
    .tag(0)
NavigationView {
    SettingsView()
        .environmentObject(userSettings) // pass here
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that was impossible since i declared it as "final"!

Comment: @LukeCrouch `final` means that it can't be subclassed/overridden - see https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/the-final-keyword/